# Error sales order grid using column search

Tags: magento-1.9, module, grid, order-grid

I created a custom module to extend the sales order grid with a SKU column. It works well, until you search in that specific column.

Then I do receive a error message.

How can I solve this?

Then I got the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(468): Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer::filterSkus(Object(Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Resource_Sales_Order_Grid_Collection), Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column)) #1 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(457): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_addColumnFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column)) #2 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(534): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_setFilterValues(Array) #3 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection() #4 /app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php on line 60
```

The file looks like this:

```
class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Joins extra tables for adding custom columns to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
     * @param Varien_Object $observer
     * @return Atwix_Exgrid_Model_Observer
     */
    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));

        $select->join(
                array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
                'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"',
                array('postcode')
            );

        $select->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));
        $select->group('main_table.entity_id'); 
    }

    /**
     * callback function used to filter collection
     * @param $collection
     * @param $column
     * @return $this
     */
    public function filterSkus($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->having(
            "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at which line is line 60, but you can like just replace the two `return $this;` statements with `return;`.